# What type returns the get method?

Tags: java, list, generics

If the type variable is a wildcard, what return type of the method will be?

```
public class MyClass{ }

List<? extends MyClass> nms = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
nms.add(new MyClass()); //compilation error
MyClass n = nms.get(0); //compiles fine
```

The thing is the return type of the `get` is not the pure `MyClass` type. Eclipse's telling me that it's `CAP#2` and the argument of the add method is `CAP#1` where `CAP#2` is a subtypeof `MyClass`, but `MyClass` is not a subtypeof `CAP#1`?

So, I'm interested where for compiler the captured type is in class hierarchy? If we create

```
public class MySubClass extends MyClass{ }
```

will `CAP#2` be a subtype of `MySubClass` either?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `<? extends MyClass>` is an *unknown* class that extends `MyClass` (can be `MyClass` itself). There is no guarantee that it has any relationship to `MySubClass`.

Replace `MyClass` with `Number` and `MySubClass` with `BigDecimal`. Then you have `<? extends Number>`. That could be `Long`. `Long` has nothing to do with `BigDecimal` (even though both extend `Number`).

As for the two methods, `get` will return something that is a `MyClass`. `add` will only accept instances of the unknown type (and since the compiler cannot enforce much about unknown types, it won't let you add anything except `null`).

Answer (score 5):

Even if you know that

```
class MySubClass extends MyClass{ }
```

the compiler is not entirely sure that the object you want to **add** to the list is compliant with the restriction of *unknown subtype of MyClass*, because nothing ca guarantee that *"unknown"* can be `MySubClass`. Therefore, it raises an error.

This is [well-known as PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs).

So, having your list define as:

```
List<? extends MyClass> nms = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
```

you will be able to add nothing **but** the `null` reference, because it's the only compliant with *"unknown"*

Comment: So does that mean this syntax is basically useless??? If so, why does the compiler even allow it???

Comment: It's not useless. This is a type of a list which you can only read from. Please read carefully the link I provided about PECS and you will get the difference. :)

Comment: "a type of a list which you can only read from". And that is very useful for a method signature that does not unneccesarily limit its parameter type, for example.